# make an event happen at specific time

Tags: angular

I've got a booking app. The user can book an appointment. For that he will choose an hour (let's say 4PM) and a part of the app will be available for him at 4PM. I've got a button "Use" that is usable at the time of the booking.

Do you know a way to make my button usable without having to refresh the page constantly ? I've got around 50 users and a lot of bookings so I can't refresh the page constantly to make the button usable. Is there a way to do that ?

For the moment I'm using interval to refresh the page every minute. I don't have any code to display as I don't have any idea how to make that possible.

html :

```
    <div *ngIf="
        (bookings.startDate | date: 'HH:mm') <= startTime &&
        (bookings.endDate | date: 'HH:mm') > startTime">
      <button (click)="selectedBook(bookings)">
        Use
      </button>
    </div>
```

ts :

```
const todayDate = new Date();
this.startTime = this.datePipe.transform(todayDate, 'HH:mm');

  selectedBook(booking) {
    const id = booking.id;
    this.router.navigate([`./place/${id}`]);
  }
```

Comment: do you have a backend? I would be handling this from there and then using a library like SignalR, to handle choosing between websockets, long polling and polling,  to then push that the Use part of the app is now available without the client needing a page refresh

Comment: The ans from JOshua might solve your prob but I would recommend websockets. what you are doing is polling and if it is a booking app then the endpoint has to handle lot of req when the peak season comes. I would recommend to have some kind of event sent from websockets , and then you listen to it and manage state of buttons. In that way, the server has control over how the status of user button should be checked. There are several ways to do that. But polling would be the shortest and worst approach in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup an observable that emits a boolean value based on your condition. And have that wrapped inside an interval that emits every second (or longer if need be).

```
public canBook$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  mapTo(new Date()),
  map(now => (this.bookings.startDate <= now) && (this.bookings.endDate > now)),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

If the date formats do not match, you can add another `map()` to convert the `new Date()` into the format you need before checking the conditional.

The `distinctUntilChanged()` operator ensures the observable doesn't keep emitting `false` every second. It will only emit a new value if it is different from the previous one.

Then in your template file.

```
<div *ngIf="canBook$ | async">
  <button (click)="selectedBook(bookings)">
    Use
  </button>
</div>
```